# How to fix docker-compose installing problem?

Tags: ubuntu, docker-compose

There are no problems with docker. I install docker-compose on ubuntu 20 launched on Virtual Box. Following [instruction](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/) for Linux:

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.28.5/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

something was installed (table with downloading info was shown).

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

there is not output. Then this command to check:

```
docker-compose --version
```

After that error was shown:

```
[4989] Error -3 from inflate: incorrect data check
[4989] Error decompressing _decimal.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
Failed to write all bytes for _decimal.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
fwrite: Bad address
```

What is the reason? How to check is it installed?

Comment: I'd suggest `apt install docker-compose`. If you don't want that and above installation instructions don't work, notify their author instead. Point is, installing stuff is not really a programming question but one of general software use. E.g. superuser.com or askubuntu.com would be more appropriate places to ask.

Comment: this command failed "...E: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/pool/stable/amd64/docker-ce-cli_20.10.5~3-0~ubuntu-focal_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried simply deinstalling and reinstalling docker-compose?
According to this [thread](https://forums.docker.com/t/error-from-inflate-when-running-docker-compose/50810/2) on the docker forum, this seems to have fixed the issue for a user who had the same problem as you.